# Dynamo DB M:N relationship issue

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, data-modeling, dynamodb-queries

I'm working on a data modeling challenge in DynamoDB involving two entities: **Class** and **Student**. I have **several million records** for **Student** and a **few hundred** for **Class**. A Student can belong to multiple Classes, and a Class can have multiple Students.

**Access Pattern Challenge:**
I need to efficiently list all Students who are not enrolled in a specified Class. The primary challenges I'm facing are:

1. DynamoDB does not support querying based on negative conditions directly.
2. Avoiding full table scans.
3. Minimizing application-level filtering. Given these constraints, how can I model my data in DynamoDB to support this access pattern through a single query operation?

**Additional Context:**

The solution should ideally allow retrieval of full profile details for each **Student**.
The dataset includes **several million Student records**, which necessitates a highly efficient querying approach.

Comment: What's your primary access pattern and why did you choose DynamoDB as your data store?

Comment: List all students that are not there in the current class . 
Dynamo was the right candidate for scalability considerations

Comment: I don't see how this could be implemented in an efficient way using DynamoDB. You'd have to store an item for each student class combination the student isn't enrolled in. At this point you'll probably be better served by a relational database if this is something that's changing and being queried frequently or by exporting the data to S3 and using Athena for ad-hoc queries (e.g. if you need to determine which students to send a notification about the course for once per week).